# How to fix 'Unexpected end of input' Error

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked at several other questions with this error, and none of the solutions in them have worked. I'm using a textbook, and it has me copy code from a website and paste it inside of a script tag (it doesn't say to paste it inside of a script tag, it just says paste it into an HTML document). I keep getting a 'Syntax error: Unexpected end of input' at the closing script tag in the code below:

```
<script>
            (function () {
                "use strict";

                var app = WinJS.Application;
                var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

                app.onactivated = function (args) {
                    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {

                        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().
                            done(function () {

                            }));
                    }
                };
            (function () {
                "use strict";

                var app = WinJS.Application;
                var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

                app.onactivated = function (args) {
                    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {

                        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().
                        done(function () {

                        // Add an event handler to the button.
                        document.querySelector("#requestPosition").addEventListener("click",
                            requestPosition);

                        }));
                    }
                };

                var nav = null;

                function requestPosition() {
                    if (nav == null) {
                        nav = window.navigator;
                    }

                    var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
                    if (geoloc != null) {
                        geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
                    }

                }

                function successCallback(position) {
                    document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML =
                        position.coords.latitude;
                    document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML =
                        position.coords.longitude;

                }

                function errorCallback(error) {
                    var strMessage = "";

                    // Check for known errors
                    switch (error.code) {
                        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                            strMessage = "Access to your location is turned off. " +
                                "Change your settings to turn it back on.";
                            break;
                        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                            strMessage = "Data from location services is " +
                                "currently unavailable.";
                            break;
                        case error.TIMEOUT:
                            strMessage = "Location could not be determined " +
                                "within a specified timeout period.";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = strMessage;
                }

                app.start();
            }()
        </script>
```

This is in the last chapter and only the first part of the exercise, so any help is appreciated. Things I've previously tried included adding another parenthesis at the end of the JavaScript, but that resulted in a different error. If it helps, this is in the MTA HTML5 workbook, Lesson 10

Comment: It looks like your first IIFE is missing a closing `)`.

Comment: Where should I put the closing parenthesis? (This came off of a website so I don't fully understand how all of it works)

Comment: It looks like you need to add `});` right before the second `(function` line.

Comment: Thank you, that solved that issue

Answer (score 0):

You repeating first part of the javascript code, and missing the ")" closing the function declaration;

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function(args) {
  if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
    args.setPromise(
      WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function() {
        // Add an event handler to the button.
        document
          .querySelector("#requestPosition")
          .addEventListener("click", requestPosition);
      })
    );
  }
};

var nav = null;

function requestPosition() {
  if (nav == null) {
    nav = window.navigator;
  }

  var geoloc = nav.geolocation;
  if (geoloc != null) {
    geoloc.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
  }
}

function successCallback(position) {
  document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  var strMessage = "";

  // Check for known errors
  switch (error.code) {
  case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
    strMessage =
      "Access to your location is turned off. " +
      "Change your settings to turn it back on.";
    break;
  case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
    strMessage =
      "Data from location services is " + "currently unavailable.";
    break;
  case error.TIMEOUT:
    strMessage =
      "Location could not be determined " +
      "within a specified timeout period.";
    break;
  default:
    break;
}

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = strMessage;
}

app.start();
})();
```